# Solution for Recursion Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Define a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}_0}$ recursively by $a_1=1$ and $$a_n=a_{n-1}+\frac{1}{a_{n-1}}$$ for $n\geq 2$. How can I prove that $12\leq a_{75}\leq 15$?

Comment: A duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1401132/11619)