# Finding range of value of 75th term in recurrence

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, recurrence-relations, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let sequence {$a_n$} be defined as below.
$a_1=1$, when $n\geq1$, $a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{1}{a_n}$

$ a_{75} $ lies between:
A) (12,15)
B) (15,18)
C) (11,12)
D) None

An easy observation is that $ a_{75} $ = Σ$\frac{1}{a_n}$ for n=$1$ to $74$

Beyond this I have been able to approximate the values to find a trivial convergence(if any) but found that many initial terms had values in $10$th decimal place (for eg $1,0.5,0.34$ etcetera) so it's difficult to approximate.

I have an intuition that we might have some solution by denoting $ a_n $ with separate variables and integration, but wasn't able to simplify any further due to too many variables.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solve the sequences inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1401132/solve-the-sequences-inequality) Found using Approach0.

Comment: Have you made a spreadsheet and computed the terms?  Copy down makes it easy.  What have you tried?

Comment: Easy to verify with picture of short and tall rectangles, around the graph of $f(x) = (1/x)$ that $$ \sum_{k=2}^{n} \frac{1}{k} < \int_{1}^n  \frac{1}{x}~dx = \log(n) < \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k}.$$